# iOS Simulator is Crashing on startup

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode12

I am using Xcode 12 with the iOS 13.4 Simulator. On bootup, I get this crash report.

> Failed to start launchd sim: could not bind to session, launchd sim may have crashed or quit responding.

What can cause this? It works in Xcode 11 but not in Xcode 12.

Comment: I have seen in some other questions that restarting the machine or wifi you're solved this issue. It is worth a try

Comment: I tried restarting my computer and reinstalling Xcode. Nothing is working

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Derived Data folder? (Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data (Click the little arrow) -> Delete the folder for your project), or creating a new simulator?

Comment: Try deleting simulator settings. When simulator is active, Go to `Device -> Erase All Content and Settings`.

Comment: It seems when I run Xcode in sudo mode, it fails to run the simulator. When I don't run it in sudo, it works just fine. How can I change the settings of my Xcode project, so I can run it in non sudo mode? I can only open the project in sudo mode.

Comment: Have the same Problem ... @kerim.ba The simulator won't boot, so there is NO active device.

Comment: @Chris Did you find a workaround? I can't even boot with simctl from command line ... without any Xcode started.

Comment: @OliverD I just updated to Big Sur 11.0.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it problem was my project had permissions that it can only run in sudo mode. When I tried to run the simulator in sudo mode, it failed. I had to change the permissions of my project, to be able to run in non sudo mode. When this happened, I could run the iOS simulator perfectly fine.

Comment: how did you do that can you edit your answer and show please ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you make yourself Admin and run below commands on Terminal:

```
sudo chown root:admin /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
sudo chown root:wheel /private/tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /private/tmp
```

Comment: Can you add to your post and explain what those commands do?