# When running on older iOS Simulator, error "Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding"

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-silicon

I'm running Xcode 12.2 (12B45b) on my M1 MacBook Pro. Whenever I try to run the simulator on an older iOS, for example:

[image: iPhone 11 Pro (13.0)]

It doesn't work. Xcode pops up this error:

[image: Failed to start launchd_sim...]

When I press on <kbd>Details</kbd>, a screen pops up showing:

```
Details

Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding
Domain: com.apple.SimLaunchHostService.RequestError
Code: 4
--


System Information

macOS Version 11.0 (Build 20A2411)
Xcode 12.2 (17535) (Build 12B45b)
Timestamp: 2020-12-06T12:41:11-08:00
```

However, If I run a newer iOS like 14.2, it works perfectly. This was the runtime that came preinstalled with Xcode.

[image: Working perfectly]

I looked at this question, [iOS Simulator is Crashing on startup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64071652/14351818), but the answer is almost useless. Some other people have had the same problem on the [Dev Forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667088), but no one has a solution yet either.

**Edit:** It seems there is a mention of this on the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode-Release-Notes/xcode-12_2-release-notes) for Xcode 12.2:

> Simulator runtimes for iOS 13, tvOS 13, and watchOS 6 and earlier don’t work on the Developer Transition Kit. Preferences offers these runtimes for download, but creating a simulated device from one of these runtimes fails, claiming the runtime is unavailable. **Other Macs with Apple silicon support a limited set of older simulator runtimes for iOS** and tvOS. (66115743, 70472441) (FB8157217)

Comment: There is no solution. Older simulators don't work on an M1.

Comment: @matt oh... do you know the lowest version that works? I'd like to get more details about this if I can

Comment: @matt That’s not accurate. Per @aheze’s own answer, it looks like a point update to Big Sur was required.

Comment: @Hanse00 It was quite accurate at the time. I didn't say they _never_ would work. It was early days. It still is, really. Lots of wrinkles remain to be ironed out...

Comment: @matt Fair enough I guess, I don’t know down to the second when you posted your message, and when the patch was up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like it's fixed in **Big Sur 11.0.1**!

[image: Running on iOS 13 simulator]

[image: "About this mac" description]

As a side note, updating your M1 Mac is *really* fast! It literally took 20 minutes.

Answer (score 106):

I solved this problem by removing simulator caches in:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

macOS Monterey 12.0.1, Xcode 13.3.1

Comment: Worked for me. The project hadn't been run in a month so maybe some background Xcode update changed something? I trashed the dyld folder and tried again, all good. Thanks!

Comment: Just run this in the Terminal: `sudo rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches`

Comment: No need for sudo!

Comment: i have the issue after i restarted the mac. and deleting the cache  as above works

Comment: the first open terminal, then typing: open ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches

Comment: This solved my problem for opening the simulator through react-native's metro bundler. Thank you os much, and as well thanks to Janserik and Морт (the command is right, but there's no need for sudo).

Answer (score 8):

Please check the permission.I have fixed the issue by running the following command in terminal

```
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: As absurd as it might sound, this fixed the problem for us.

Comment: By chance is there an explanation somewhere for why this would fix the issue?  Just ran into this problem and did this and simulators launch again.

Answer (score 0):

Running this in the terminal resolved my problem.

```
open -a Simulator
```