# Can not launch simulator or preview either

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, preview

I updated my mac system to 11.4 and xcode to 12.5 and this issue happened to me yesterday ,i had tried many ways to sovle it, but still didn’t work, anyone who can tell me how to fix this please!
[preview issues screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDnjt.png)
[simulator issues screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwS8b.png)

Comment: [Happened to me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65172944/14351818) before in macOS 11.0. Which simulator model are you using?

Comment: I would suggest: quit Xcode, throw away all simulators manually, restart computer. However, note that I have not done this exact update yet.